# In Soul Music, where do the corn fields behind Death garden come from?

Tags: discworld

In *Soul Music*, Susan explores multiple times the area surrounding Death's cottage. Everything is how we are used to know it, with the predominance of black and the constant feeling that things are odd because, well, Death has no real experience of things and thus can never get anything really right.

But in *Soul Music* Susan finds, behind the usual garden area, a "real" field of corn with everything perfectly in place, colours included.

Is this a nod to Death experience as Bill Door in *Reaper Man*? Do we see Death creating them, in any of the books?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes. Death created the golden fields of corn at the end of Reaper Man, after being restored as the Death of Discworld, and after wrapping up his life as Bill Door.

> Death stood at the window of his dark study, looking out on to his garden. Nothing moved in that still domain. Dark lilies bloomed by the trout pool, where little plaster skeleton gnomes fished. There were distant mountains.
>
> It was his own world. It appeared on no map.
>
> But now, somehow, it lacked something.

...

> He snapped his fingers. Fields appeared, following the gentle curves of the land.
>
> "Golden", said Albert. "That's nice. I've always thought we could do with  a bit more colour around here."

Reaper Man - p285 - Corgi paperback 1992

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I have read The Reaper Man a long time ago and didn't remember this part at all. Which, now that I think of it, is quite weird...how many chances are there that it's been removed in the Italian edition? O_o

Comment: @motoDrizzt I only remember because I've read this book somewhere close to twenty times - it was my favourite Discworld book for quite some time...

Comment: I'm thinking of slightly edit the question. As it stands it's more about me not remembering things than a proper question about Death and the fields. Nothing big, I'll simply change it so to mainly ask where the crop fields are from. I'll keep your answer accepted, it still fits the question, but keep an eye on it if you too want to rephrase it slightly differently